# Apache FOP: failed to load and use custom font

Tags: java, apache, fonts, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I want to use a custom font (Vito-Regular.otf) for the pdf documents generated inside a java programm - using Apache FOP 2.1.

Most of the samples found on the web refer to FOP 1.0 and .ttf fonts. So this will help me at all.

My FOP user config:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<fop version="1.0">
  <renderers>
    <renderer mime="application/pdf">
      <fonts>
        <font embed-url="file:C://Windows//Fonts//Vito-Regular.otf" kerning="yes" >
          <font-triplet name="Vito" style="normal" weight="normal" />
        </font>
      </fonts>
    </renderer>
  </renderers>
```

Using in the template:

```html
    <fo:block-container font-size="9pt" font-family="Vito">
```

Will lead to use the default font (any) but not the (for me expected) Vito font:

```
WARNUNG: Font "Vito,normal,400" not found. Substituting with "any,normal,400".
```

So here are my main questions on this issue:

1. Is there a way to check/read the loaded fonts in Apache FOP 2.1?
2. Is the combination of 'Vito,normal,400' equivalent to name,style,weight?
3. Is the configuration of the font correct set? Even not what have I overseen?
4. Is the font correct referenced in the template?
5. Is there a way to check if the font is compatible with Apache FOP?

Any help on these questions is appreciated.

Comment: Sometimes the (absolute windows) file: URLs are a bit strage, have you tried adding some 1-4 `/` between file: and C: like `file://C:/` ? On linux I use `file:///home` for an absolute path starting with `/home`

Comment: Also, I think the double `//` are a relict of once-escaped \\ and one `/` at each path position should be enough.

Comment: nope, none of the combinations solve the problem. I do not think that this is the problem at all. something might be wrong configured but I have no clue what...

Comment: Likely you're right, my experiments would give exceptions when the file itself would not be found, in contrast to then the font entry would not even match. You might try mailing this on the FOP users list and make them the files available they usually are very helpful.

Comment: Are you actually telling FOP to _use_ the configuration file? (`-c path/to/fop.xconf` from the command line, or `fopFactory.setUserConfig(...)` in the Java code)

Comment: @lfurini: yes, I configured it with the fopFactory and it uses this config file

Answer (score 0):

My fop.xml is like this

```
<renderers>
<renderer mime="application/pdf">
  <fonts>
    <font embed-url="MSMINCHO.TTF" kerning="yes" sub-font="MS Mincho">
    <font-triplet name="MS Mincho" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
    <font-triplet name="MS Mincho" style="normal" weight="bold"/>
    </font>
  </fonts>
</renderer>
```

and my `TTF` file is in the same directory as my `xml` file.

So maybe you are either missing the `sub-font` tag or there is a problem with the file location and/or file type.

Comment: Hm, okay, I added the sub-font tag and put the font to the same directory. This makes sadly no difference. The font is an open type font so therefor I cannot change this...

Answer (score 0):

It seams an URI problem under Windows (on OSX no problem). I have solved this issue with a few a workaround.

My java code is standard

```
String filename = "xfop.xml";
FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance(new File (filename));
```

First

```
<font-base>\\<computername>\C$\Windows\Fonts</font-base>
```

Second, please note note that localhost does not work,

```
<font-base>\\127.0.0.1\Windows\fonts</font-base>
```

Third, I copy the fonts I need in (and this is my production solution)

```
<font-base>\\<server>\<share>\fonts</font-base>
```